# sshd execs on new connection rather than fork

Tags: centos7, sshd

I am facing strange issue with sshd on centos 7. I start `/sbin/sshd -ddd -D` on one terminal of my server. Lets say its PID is $sshdpid 
* connect from another m/c

On **successful connection**, I see that $sshdpid instead of showing `/sbin/sshd -ddd -D` shows `sshd: root@pts/0`

And now what happens is that when the client interactive session completes (exits). The $sshdpid remains no more in the server. It implies sshd server is not running. I see following logs:

*on stdout*:

```
Received disconnect from 10.10.73.40 port 36348:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from 10.10.73.40 port 36348
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: closing session
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering

[1]+  Exit 255                /sbin/sshd -ddd -D
```

I see following logs in /var/logs/messages in server.

```
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: Received disconnect from 10.10.73.40 port 60586:11: disconnected by user
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: Disconnected from 10.10.73.40 port 60586
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: debug1: do_cleanup
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: debug1: PAM: closing session
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
Jun  3 11:23:57 master sshd: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Jun  3 11:23:57 master systemd: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Jun  3 11:23:57 master systemd: sshd.service failed.
Jun  3 11:23:57 master systemd-logind: Removed session 13.
Jun  3 11:24:39 master systemd: sshd.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun  3 11:24:39 master systemd: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
```

I am sshing from client as `root login`

Please help. I am unable to debug this issue. :(

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `-d` option that you're using? This is exactly what it's supposed to do: process one connection then quit.

Comment: *facepalm* sorry about my naive ques. you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I was debugging slow ssh login and had mistakenly put `-ddd in /usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service` . Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: how do I close the question. self-answer ?